# writing own oh-my-zsh plugin

Tags: plugins, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to write a simple plugin for `oh-my-zsh` completing only possible server arguments.

Example 1:

```
$ myserver st    # hits tab
start stop
```

Example 2:

```
$ myserver    # hits tab
start stop restart
```

According to [wiki](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization) I have created file named `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/myserver/myserver.plugin.zsh` with sample content of [coffee plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/coffee/_coffee) (I tried [brew plugin](https://github.com/mrtazz/oh-my-zsh/blob/7b6be5611763f25eca043f9ed0d46066a3454205/functions/brew/_brew) as well) but completition doesn't work (any of described in file). Moreover error is thrown:

```
_arguments:comparguments:312: can only be called from completion function
```

I checked similar problems and my `fpath` includes `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/myserver`.

What am I missing? This should be pretty simple... Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your post I'd assume that you have named the file `myserver.plugin.zsh`, however, if it is used to define a completion function its name must start with an underscore. It seems to be customary that the underscore is followed by the command name, i.e. in your case `_myserver`.

However, without the explicit code **you** are using I can not help you any further. You might want to check [this](http://askql.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/zsh-writing-own-completion/) blog post for further help.

I should remark that it is completely unnecessary to design a completion function as `oh-my-zsh` plugin; just create it as standalone piece of code.

Comment: thanks you, I really couldn't find this tutorial. For future readers - create folder `completions` rather than `completion` and you may let `.zshrc` unmodified.